# Cordova / PhoneGap move file from file:///var/mobile/Applications/ to dom allowed reading location

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser, cordova

my 'whitelabel' app downloads image files from a configuration server to customise itself for each client.

however it won't display the images, instead showing a "Not allowed to load local resource" error.

is there a way i can move my files from locations like "file:///var/mobile/Applications/01AD1275-1FF9-41C6-8A25-B1E344055AF3/Documents/" to somewhere that my app is allowed to load from or generate data uris from these files using cordova's file api? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its not the location i think. You have to give your app the permission in the manifest / config

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
```

Comment: skillz! thank you so much. i thought i would have to read them as data uris using the file api.